# Compilation error when archiving Xamarin iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am about to distribute my iOS app, when I archive the project I get the following error:

```
/Users/luissalas/Downloads/AppCitas/AppCitas/AppCitas.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void ObjCRuntime.DisposableObject::Dispose()', referenced from the method 'Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile Plugin.Media.ELCImagePickerViewController::GetPictureMediaFile(AssetsLibrary.ALAsset,System.Int64)' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**********'. (MT2101) (AppCitas.iOS)
```

All NuGet packages are updated, I am working on

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Xamarin.iOS 14.0
- XCode 12.0
- Mono 6.12.0.199
- Xamarin.Foms 5.0.0.2622
- Visual Studio 17.6.8
- NuGet 6.4.0.117

The compilation in Debug and Release mode runs fine in the simulator, but is impossible for me to archive the project.

The old programmer managed to deploy the app in the appstore, I was just hired to update it, I suppose the problem is related to versions, since my Mac is old, it does not allow me to install later versions of XCode 12.4 for iOS 14.4.
I have tried to downgrade the versions of Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.iOS, Mono, Visual Studio and XCode but the problem does not disappear, now I am working with the most recent versions that my computer allows me to install and it is impossible for me to archive the project.

I have tried all the linker behavior options and the problem persists:
[IMAGE : iOS Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvxm2.png)

[IMAGE : iOS Bundle Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhIge.png)

About Visual Studio:

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Versión 17.6.8 (build 400)
UUID de instalación: b89db20f-1fcc-4715-ac13-331b0a217ca2

Runtime
.NET 7.0.3 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64
Microsoft.macOS.Sdk 13.1.1007; git-rev-head:8afca776a0a96613dfb7200e0917bb57f9ed5583; git-branch:release/7.0.1xx-xcode14.2

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.6.3.9
Hash: 2648399ae8
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-6
Build date: 2024-01-03 23:07:48 UTC

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.6.0-3.23180.6+99e956e42697a6dd886d1e12478ea2b27cceacfa

NuGet
Versión: 6.4.0.117

SDK de .NET (x64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.312/Sdks
Versiones del SDK:
    7.0.312
    6.0.418
    5.0.408
    3.1.420
SDK de MSBuild: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Versiones de tiempo de ejecución:
    7.0.15
    6.0.26
    5.0.17
    3.1.26

Xamarin.Profiler
Versión: 1.8.0.49
Ubicación: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Versión: 11

Herramientas de desarrollo de Apple
Xcode: 12.0 17219
Compilación: 12A7209

Xamarin.iOS
Versión: 14.0.0.0 Visual Studio Community
Hash: 7ec3751a1
Rama: xcode12
Fecha de la compilación: 2020-09-16 11:33:15-0400

Sistema operativo
Mac OS X 10.15.7
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0
    Tue Jun 21 21:18:39 PDT 2022
    root:xnu-6153.141.66~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: You cannot publish iOS apps to the AppStore with Xcode 12 anymore. Since April 2023, all apps have to be built with Xcode 14.1 or higher (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jd9wcyov) and starting April 2024, all apps are required to be built using Xcode 15 (https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/).